# How to remove anything from string after whitespaces in java

Tags: java, android

I have a String like this: `12/16/2011 12:00:00 AM`
now i want to show only date part i.e `12/16/2011` on Textview
and remove the other part. What shall i need to do for this??

Any help will be appricated
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just two simple possibilities:

```
String str = "12/16/2011 12:00:00 AM";

// method 1: String.substring with String.indexOf
str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' '));

// method 2: String.split, with limit 1 to ignore everything else
str.split(" ", 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

Use java.text.DateFormat to parse the String into a Date and then reformat to display it as you wish with another DateFormat:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
inputFormat.setLenient(false);
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
outputFormat.setLenient(false);
Date d = inputFormat.parse("12/16/2011 12:00:00 AM");
String s = outputFormat.format(d);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "11/12/2011 12:20:10 AM";

    int i = str.indexOf(" ");
    str = str.substring(0,i);
    Log.i("TAG", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this below code to get sub string

```
String thisString="Hello world";

String[] parts = theString.split(" ");
String first = parts[0];//"hello"
String second = parts[1];//"World"
```

Answer (score 0):

using a regular expression (more robust than others - works even when there is no whitespace found)

```
str.replaceAll(" .*", "");
```

Comment: please withdraw your comment, I just tried the code and it indeed does work... of course, you need to use the result of the function call

Comment: ohh I am sorry that was my mistake I didn't print the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = myString.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "));
```

or

```
myString = myString.split(" ", 1)[0];
```